# Xamarin Project on Android emulator having an SSL issue when sending requests to back end hosted through ngrok

Tags: android, asp.net, asp.net-core, ssl, ngrok

I've inherited some code from someone who used to work for my company. Its a fairly simple Xamarin project that has releases on iOS and Android. It hasn't been touched in several years so I've been tasked with updating it with a few new features.

The back end for this app is a ASP.NET Core Web App targeting .NET 4.6.1 and is running in visual studio 2022 in administrator mode, and that is the middle man between the app and our databases. The app sends requests to the back end, the back end fetches the data, and returns it to the app, etc.

For development, the app is run in local IIS, then routed through ngrok. I run it in a command prompt run as administrator using the command

```
ngrok http --host-header=rewrite http://localhost:62527/
```

This generates a URL that I can use to send requests to the back end from the app

The Xamarin code is run through an android emulator through windows studio 2022 run in administrator mode

I had some troubles with it initially through my companies VPN, once I disconnected from the VPN the requests would actually go through, I put a breakpoint in the back end before it sent a request to the database,  then I would have to reconnect to the VPN and it would work for at least one request. It seemed like once I got past that part of it the VPN wasn't a problem

This worked perfectly for me for a good while, until it just suddenly started giving me problems again. I went through all the steps I took to get it working the first time, including messing around with the VPN, and its still giving me problems

Now any time I try to send a request to the back end through the emulator I get the following message

> Ssl error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED
> at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/boringssl/ssl/handshake_client.c:1132

Shortly before I had this I had to reset my emulator because it was giving me problems, and I can't help but wonder if somehow the emulator itself has some kind of cert. This is backed up somewhat by the fact that I can send requests to the ngrok URL through postman and it goes through no problem. The code for the HTTP requests has not changed in any way.

I've tried connecting to a physical android device, switching emulators, and I also ran

```
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

To try and get the cert to be trusted

I can't help but wonder if something on my network changed as well. Am I just missing something here with the emulator or is there something I need to talk to my IT people about? I have a ticket open with them but I'd like to go in as prepared as possible

Comment: Since this was working and now it is not, the first thing I would check is make sure the Certificates are still valid, make sure they have not expired.